# Can't Connect LG G Pad V410 to Android Studio on Mac OS X

Tags: debugging, android-studio, usb, connect, tablet

I spent hours trying to figure out how to connect my LG G Pad V410 to Android Studio and didn't find any answers online. After playing around with my settings long enough I came across a simple fix that doesn't require you to tamper with your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Begin by making sure you have developer tools enabled on your device.
2. Go to Settings -> About Tablet -> Software Info
3. Tap the "Build Number" box 7 times to enable developer tools.
4. Go to Settings -> Storage
5. Look in the top right corner of the screen for the three dots (more settings tab) and click "USB PC connection.
6. Make sure "Send Images (PTP)" is selected.

That should fix your problem!